# Too many request to server using jquery autocomplete function

Tags: php, jquery, performance, database-performance

Suppose i have thousands of items in database,and i want to make them searchable using some sort of autocomplete like jQuery autocomplete,but i don't want to use ajax as with each key press a request will be made to database.

I can use this one without ajax.

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

But if as i have thousands of items,this will also impact on server and website speed ?

Is it wise able to first fetch all records and place them in a seprate file and then search it form there,in order to make website more speedy and less load on the server?

Comment: You don't have to make a request after each keypress. You should debounce the event so that a request is only made after typing has stopped for 0.5s or so. Also, any server should be able to handle searching through a few thousand records, so long as your datastore is configured properly. As for your latter solution, that would probably perform slower and choke the server up with requests.

Comment: And to prevent that the ajax call will return too much data, check the number of rows in the result. Only if it falls below a certain maximum you respond with these results. Alternatively you could rank the result and only show the most probable ones.

Comment: So you mean by storing all records once or on daily basis in the file will also slow down the process of searching ? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @KhiradBanu yes, for two reasons. Firstly file access is much, much slower than a well optimised database. Secondly, you would need to return the whole file every time, whereas the DB can filter for you and return only the required data

Comment: Ok got it,thank you@RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Thank you for such useful suggestion @KIKOSoftware

Answer (score 2):

If you have thousands of records, of course you will need use ajax, otherwise you will be loading a lot of data on client-side, exposing the entire information to someone that want's to steal it, also slowing down the page loading.

The are two ways to reduce requests:

## Implement a debounce

A debounce is just a timer, that wait X milliseconds before doing the request. If the user types something before this timer finish, you cancel it and start another.

**Downside**: It needs a fine tuning on the debounce time so user don't feel some lag.

## Cancel the requests

You can trigger a request on every key press, but if another key is pressed, you cancel the previous request. This may reduce the load on server, since the requests may not be finished yet.

**Downside**: It only reduces the load on server if the user type faster then server response time.

## Combining Debounce with Cancel Request

If you combine both the techniques above, you will have a good result, because you can reduce the debounce time to have an imperceptible delay, and also cancel the pending requests if user types slowly.